# Python Pandas, create more efficient loop for filter with reference to current and previous index

Tags: python, performance, pandas, filtering

I have a pandas dataframe with an index and data, i.e.

```
pd.DataFrame([0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4,4,3.5,3,2.5,2,1.5,1,0.5], index=[range(1,18)], columns=['Value'])
```

I want to make calculations on each row based on values of the current index (i) and previous index (i-1). Is there a more efficient way of making this calculation on a very large dataset? I haven't had much luck finding another solution.

This is what I have so far...

```
def filter(df, alpha):
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        x_i = row['Value']
        if i == 1: 
            # initialise data
            y_i = x_i
        else: 
            # calculate filtered value
            y_i = (alpha * y_i_1) + (0.5 * (1 + alpha) * (x_i - x_i_1))
        qf_list.append(y_i)
        # set (i-1) values for next loop
        y_i_1 = y_i
        x_i_1 = x_i
    return qf_list, qb_list
```

Note: this is a filter that isn't found in scipy and isn't for signal processing

Comment: The simplest way to do it is probably to add a new column containing the shifted indices.  Then you can just access those values as an ordinary column.

Comment: I considered this approach, however was not sure how to make it work. I need two values at (i-1) the first is from the original dataframe (i.e. 'Values') and the second from a new list/dataframe column (i.e. say 'NewValues'). So the new value is dependant on the previous new value as well...

Comment: Not sure if I understand you.  Are you saying that the value you want to compute in row N depends on the value you computed in the previous iteration for row N-1?  If that is so, and you have no way of removing that recurrence, I don't see how you can avoid looping over the rows.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean. If there is no way of avoiding it, is this likely the most efficient way to loop through rows?

Comment: If you are going for the loop approach, maybe you can speed it up by taking out the column(s) you want to work on, and using integer indexes on those, instead of iterating over the rows, which is probably slower.
Also, often there IS a way to vector process the columns, even though the formulas appear to depend on the result from the previous row. It depends on the exact formulas, of course.